# Is the $L^{p}$ norm smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations

Let $p>1$ and consider the function 
$$\phi(t):=\int_{\Omega}|f+t\,g|^{p},$$ where $f,g\in L^{p}({\Omega})$, and $\Omega$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.
It is known that $\phi$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ with
$$\phi^{\prime}(t):=\frac{p}{2}\int_{\Omega}|f+t\,g|^{p-2}
((f+tg)\bar{g}+(\bar{f}+t\bar{g})g).$$
(See for example  "Analysis" of Lieb and Loss).

Is $\phi$ continuously differentiable ?
Is it at least continuously differentiable  at $t=0$ ?

It is easy to show that $\phi\in C^{1}$, by Holder's inequality that allows passing the limit inside the integral that defines $\phi^{\prime}$.

My question is: Does $\phi^{\prime\prime}$ exist ? Is it continuous ?

Comment: Consider $f=0,g=1, \Omega = [0,1].$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for that function to be infinitely differentiable. The scalar function $x\mapsto |x|^p$ already fails that property, unless $p$ is an even integer. For example, 
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} |x|^3= 6|x|, $$ 
so $|x|^3$ is differentiable only two times.